# splitting array of strings by specific length of character with condition in it

Tags: vba, split

```
Function SplitString(ByVal str As String, ByVal numOfChar As Long) As String()
Dim sArr() As String
Dim nCount As Long
ReDim sArr((Len(str) - 1) \ numOfChar)
Do While Len(str)
    sArr(nCount) = Left$(str, numOfChar)
    str = Mid$(str, numOfChar + 1)
    nCount = nCount + 1
Loop
SplitString = sArr
End Function
```

Hi i was trying to split an array of strings by specific length of character inside a cell with the above code and i got the results..

But now, like for an example, This is our input data "abcd,efghijk,lmn,opqrs,tuvw", and we want to split this into substrings of 8 characters each, after splitting the data, The result will be as "abcd,efg" "hijk,lmn"(8Charcaters), ",opqrs,t(8Charcaters)", "uvw(remaining characters)"... But how i needed was after every splitting, each spliited word should stop with it's previous comma... and next charcaters that come after comma should be considered by next splitted word even it comes on the same length of characters.. like the result for the above example should be "abcd"(should end with this much, even though of 8Charcaters in the splitted word), "efghijk"(correct 8Charcaters)", "lmn"(8Charcaters, even though of 8Charcaters in the splitted word)", "opqrs"(8charcaters even though of 8Charcaters in the splitted word), "tuvw(remaining characters)". We can have multiple words separated by commas inside one substring if all that comes within 8 characters limit. Please advise.

Comment: So split on commas, then for those substrings you further break them into 8 char chunks -> `e.g. "1234,123456789abc,12345" => {"1234", "12345678", "9abc", "12345"}`? Maybe add a table of before vs after to your question. You can copy a table from Excel into markdown:  https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/ And add it to your question

Comment: 8 is just an example number i gave, actually I'm dealing with string arrays of 300 to 500 characters in length separated by multiple commas in between, and I want to segregate them in to multiple substrings of 60 characters in length. In this case, how can we rewrite the code now. Please advise. We have commas, on every 5th, 6th, 7th...up to12th, etc. occurences in the string array.

Comment: I cannot understand anything from your question, sorry... What do you mean by splitting **into substrings of 8 characters each**, since the pseudo result you wish does not return **any string of 8 characters**? Do you want meaning to split *each string between commas* by 8, **only if its length is bigger then 8**, otherwise to **keep it as it is**? If so, what to be the return for the string "1111,222222222,3333"? "1111", "22222222", "22", "3333"? If not, how to be split the string example I tried?

Comment: Sorry... I will try to explain... In here, I am considering all the characters that are included between two commas as a single piece of data (charcaters), Now what i meant was, after breaking the full array of strings into a particular number of chunks, The data component that I first mentioned shouldn't be divided into two substrings because we're aiming to break them up by a certain number of characters; instead, the cut-off data section should be included with the following substring in the outcome. If you still dont understand i'll give one of my realtime Example data

Comment: Input - PAS,PRZENOŚNIK,SZEROKOŚĆ:400 MM,DŁUGOŚĆ:110000 MM,GRUBOŚĆ:NIEDOSTĘPNE,LICZBA WARSTW:NIEDOSTĘ (92 Characters in total).... Result Coming(For 30 Characters Split) - "PAS,PRZENOŚNIK,SZEROKOŚĆ:400 M" "M,DŁUGOŚĆ:110000 MM,GRUBOŚĆ:NI" "EDOSTĘPNE,LICZBA WARSTW:NIEDOS" I need it as - "PAS,PRZENOŚNIK" "SZEROKOŚĆ:400 MM" "DŁUGOŚĆ:110000 MM" "GRUBOŚĆ:NIEDOSTĘPNE" "LICZBA WARSTW:NIEDOSTĘ" (Here, only first substring is having 2 data parts in it as it's total length is within 30, and all others are having only one data part because, it should not cut-off the data part across 2 substrings.

Comment: Why didn't you answer my specific example string? What to understand from your "Input", if you do not show the desired output? So, for my example string ("1111,222222222,3333") should the return be "1111", "22222222", "223333"? Besides that, if the string would be "1111,222222222,33333333", should the output be "1111", "22222222", "22333333", "3"?

Comment: I still cannot understand anything from your real data example... Based on what to have first string with **two comma inside**? Which to be the rule related to existing commas?

Comment: we can have multiple data parts in a single substring even after splitting, only if, that's length is lesser than 30 (In here, data part means words that are there in between commas, example, PAS is one data part and PRZENOŚNIK is another data part)

Comment: I cannot understand anything, sorry...  So, I cannot help.